# Running python script in Windows background

Tags: python, cmd

I have a long python script that runs on a Windows host for a long while (by design),
And the application that runs that script (via windows CMD) needs to receive a response quickly or else it times out.

is there a way to run the script, and have a quick "ok" output for the other application to not time out, while the script still runs in the background?

i have tried "*start py script.py*" or "*start /b py script.py*" but it does not give any response.

Comment: `start "" python "a long python script.py"` used in a  `.bat` script runs `python` in a child `cmd` instance and the `.bat` script continues.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *a quick "ok" output*? you can either start the Python script and continue the batch script (by `start` as shown by JosefZ), or you can wait for the Python script to finish in the batch script, then you can get its output...

Comment: Are you writing the application that runs the script? If so, why wait for a response? If not, what exactly is the interface you have? Can you substitute a BAT file that you wrote instead of calling the `start py ...` command directly?

Comment: Hi Guys, as all of you have suggested, the .bat script (along with an echo for a string response for the application) did the trick! Thank you very much! :)